# What is the interpretation physics of the below integral which represented in terms of plasma dispersion function?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, plasma-physics

I am not a physicist and am not familiar with Plasma physics, I have tried to evaluate some special function related to Plasma dispersion function like error function I come up to the below integral such that the value of that integral for t go to $\infty$  is  $0.994..$,

$F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \exp(-\frac{z^2}{z_0\sqrt{\pi}}(Z(iz)-\frac{1}{{\pi}})(Z(z)-z_0 \exp(-2\pi z^2)))dz$

In probability area that integral present a PDF, But really am interesting to know what this means in physics such that :$Z(iz)$ and $Z(z)$ are plasma dispersion function evaluated at complex variable $z$ and $Z(0)=i\sqrt{\pi}$  Notion of Conte 1961 (presentation of Plasma dispersion function using Faddeva function)? Now my question here How I can interpret this in physics, What would be means evaluation of that integrat at some complex numbers $z$, Any known Phenomena? And also if it is possible I want to evaluate that integral using PlasmaPy at some complex numbers ?

Comment: The plasma dispersion function is usually used to find normal modes of the system resulting from poles in the integral, e.g., when the integrand diverges you are looking at the frequency and wavenumber corresponding to the instability resonance.

Comment: @honeste_vivere,Could u pleas provide me an answer regarding that function